# Delete Range of Lines in Iterative Process

Tags: python, linux

I have a kml data file (~160,000 lines).  Within a Python script, I need to search for a keyword 'Unmatched' in the `<name>` tag and if found, remove everything from the `<Placemark>` to `</Placemark>` associated with that named entry.

I have tried the forums here and for a one time shot, it works, but when i need to perform this operation hundreds of times within the same file, I have not succeeded. There are 34 lines that need to be removed. 'prev' gets the starting line of where the delete needs to start and 'end' is where it stops... so I need to delete [prev:end] and then write those changes.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
lookup = 'Unmatched '
with open('doc.kml') as myFile:
    for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
        if lookup in line:
            print 'Found in Line:', num
            prev = num-1
            print 'Placemark Starts at line:', prev
            end = prev+33
            print '/Placemark Ends at line:', end
```

Comment: one possible way is to write lines to another list and perform manual iteration with `next` 33/34 times to skip the lines when pattern found

Comment: Can you show a small sample of the data?

Answer (score 0):

I would forget about line numbers. Focus on the contents of the line.

- store the lines in another list of lines
- when the start pattern is found, drop the remaining 33 (34?) lines by manually iterating on the file with `next`
- the "drop the *previous* line" problem can be solved by popping the last line that we stored in the output list of lines

like this:

```
lookup = 'Unmatched '
filtered = []   # output list of lines
with open('doc.kml') as myFile:
    for line in myFile:
        if lookup in line:
            filtered.pop()  # drop the line we just added
            for _ in range(34): # not sure of how many, you'll see
                next(myFile,None)  # drop a line
        else:
           filtered.append(line)

# in the end write back filtered file if needed (one could write directly instead of using a list to append to)
with open('newdoc.kml') as f:
    f.writelines(filtered)
```

Comment: Thank you Jean.  I think this approach is working better.  Where I am stuck...when I find the keyword, I need to go back one line, delete that line and the next 33 lines.  If I start deleting at the keyword line, I am off.